# How can I prevent content of before psuedo element from overflowing its width and height?

Tags: css

How can I prevent content of `before` psuedo element from overflowing its width and height?
[image]

CSS styles for this `::before` psuedo element is:

```
content: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABoAAAASCAYAAABFGc6jAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAc1JREFUOBHtlE8oBHEUx9+bYVknFMrBRcmJk9pEuXLWXhQHJ/vHvyJOrJKLsGxbW3KghDMOTiiSE22UIncuFLLszPNm1/xm5mftn4uT32W+n/e+772Z329mEKRFgfFaoEQPELowujQrpbMi+UZbAbReUJU1XFk8t5uLTKBYrBgur2dAex/jmApAG2Yu15WCY/WgJdaBkjyIl4bbco1iBGhnR4XLq00gmmDkIfgAqmtKNmdi8o82gPZxAgTpIYBb0OE5lr3pJzo67WNjt0gihDAyfy84m9CTq5yuSVkQX0EtG0SvV5NLFAoul4BO1t0j6gAV67IxE1NguJPj7VaO9nBl7tFiSymg3fXz5tVZIbrF6PSLxVmUTiFHlpQLB9vAOKMuG7PEZydnJgpOVvGZtjiyCjw52AZ8RtRsY0aqpIHhoCNmgApxjCwdirj+2iS0KXRq41rxJqfD+icUle4i+YbeuLnb9Ga9urARw+Ebw0P+ES/o2o/X+Jf6MyXvIUaHJHlEI6IyoXMLT+o7yu37dpCCeXslY2GDpOJC8H9QIbvl8P7h1hk/wvxXwmbN7zeVKsAPfiJcAMSkrUFmiRgHdB+IZHX5PtfFBf8m0r3DX43yh79W6TLRAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
transform: translate(-120%,-10%);
width: 1em;
height: 1em;
```

(the `div` to which this psuedo element belongs has `position: relative;`

**Edit**:

P.S.: I don't want to change the `content` of the psuedo element. Is it still possible?

**Edit**:

I want the pseudo element to be `16px x 16px` without cutting the image out

Comment: Have you tried by simply not using position: absolute? And perhaps adding some higher values for `width, height` to your pseudo element? PS: your question is not clear at all...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan as you can see in the image above, the image in `content` of psuedo element is going beyond 16 x 16 px. Is it clear now?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, I have added the width and height properties, you can check the CSS snippet below the screen shot

Comment: don't use content, use background image

Comment: @TemaniAfif ok. But I want to achieve the solutions WITH using `content` (as specified in the question) thanks

Comment: add overlfow:hidden then

Comment: @TemaniAfif if will cut the image, wouldn't look good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is not possible to contain the image inside `content` property of psuedo element since psuedo elements are [anonymous replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)

from MDN:
In CSS, a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) is an element whose representation is outside the scope of CSS; they're external objects whose representation is independent of the CSS formatting model.
Put in simpler terms, they're elements whose contents are not affected by the current document's styles. The position of the replaced element can be affected using CSS, but not the contents of the replaced element itself.

Thus as the other answers suggest, using `background` CSS property will the solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `:before` pseudo and using a background image at size `16px`

```css
blockquote {
  margin:0;
  max-width: 130px; /* demo only */
  padding-left: 1.5em; /* space for quote icon */
  background: 0 0.1em / 16px no-repeat  url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}
```

```html
<blockquote>Charlie, from the lorem ipsum book has a nice dog called</blockquote>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I want the image in pseudo element to be `16px x 16px` thus the question - don't want it to overflow

Comment: @EdwardTorvalds set `16px` to be the background image size. (see first example without the useless pseudo element)

Comment: please checkout my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53151430/2895710

Answer (score 0):

If you use "overflow: hidden" on the :before element is won't overflow anymore and will cut off some of the image. Else it's better to use the image as a background image and set the width of the background image to 100%. play a little with the hieght and width of the element to make it in the right ratio

```
  .box:before {
      content: '';
      background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
      background-size: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top:0;    
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it will cut the image

Comment: please checkout my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53151430/2895710

Answer (score 0):

Use scale to reduce the overall width/height and obtain what you want

```css
.box:before {
  content: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0.7);
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Using background would be the ideal solution:

```css
.box:before {
  content:"";
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') center/contain no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this code is not solving the problem of overflowing image

Comment: @EdwardTorvalds the only way is to use background-image (see the update) or use some hacks to avoid the overflow like scaling. You make it smaller so that it cover the initial space

Comment: please checkout my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53151430/2895710

Comment: @EdwardTorvalds for this particular reason I told you that you cannot and you need background or other hacks like scales.